# linewidth option not working with diagbox package and beamer

Tags: diagbox

I'm trying to make an array in a frame environment of a `beamer` presentation. I would like to make a diagonal cell in this array with the `\diagbox` command.

It works well but when I try to adjust the line thickness with `[linewidth=1.5pt]` there is no modification of the diagonal line and I don't understand why?

This is the minimal example of the problem :

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\newcolumntype{I}{!{\vrule width 1.5pt}}  %Type de ligne de colonne épaisse
\newlength\epaisseurLigne 
\newcommand\Ghline{\noalign{\global\epaisseurLigne\arrayrulewidth\global\arrayrulewidth 1.5pt}\hline \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\epaisseurLigne}} %Type de ligne de ligne épaisse
\newcommand\Gcline[1]{\noalign{\global\epaisseurLigne\arrayrulewidth\global\arrayrulewidth 1.5pt}\cline{#1} \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\epaisseurLigne}} %Type de ligne de ligne épaisse

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{I>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}I>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}I>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}I>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}I>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}@{}m{0pt}I}
\Ghline
\diagbox[linewidth=1.5pt,width=24.3mm,height=13mm]{Type}{Categorie} & CATI & CATII &  CATIII &  CATIV   &  \tabularnewline [8mm]
\Ghline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and the result :

[image]

**Do you know why the line thikness is not adjusted properly ?**

Comment: Your code compiles on my machine [looking like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EmOcI.png). That is, equivalent line widths.

Comment: I tryed again but the thickness remain the same. So I think the problem come from the LaTeX distribution provided with Debian 8.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment. As Werner, your code works fine for me (TexLive 2016) so I suggest using the last vanilla TexLive.

Beside this, if you will need to revisit that presentation often, it could be more pleasant for editing a more simplified code. For instance:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{-}{!{\vrule width 1.5pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\arrayrulewidth 1.5pt
\tabcolsep1em
\begin{tabular}{-c-c-c-c-c-}
\hline
\diagbox[linewidth=1.5pt,width=9em]{Type}{Categorie} 
& CATI & CATII &  CATIII &  CATIV   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]